# Как сделать значение колонки одной таблицы SQL суммой всех строк из другой таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sqlite

Вот есть 2 таблицы. 1ая данные о пользователях 2ая о всех покупках пользователей. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы в первой таблице определенный столбец показывал сумму всех покупок из второй таблицы пользователя по его ID? Или хотя как сделать чтобы была сумма всех строк из опр. таблицы. Простите за такие вопросы, изучаю SQL не так давно.
Тестировал

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS asd (n INT DEFAULT (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users));
```

, но это не работет

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы в первой таблице автоматически обновлялась ячейка с суммой всех покупок при вставке во вторую строку?

Comment: @Viktorov скорее хотят вычисляемый столбец.

Comment: @Viktorov Да, именно так, чтобы в первой таблице автоматически обновлялась ячейка с суммой всех покупок при вставке во вторую таблицу.

Comment: Почитайте про триггеры, другого способа решить вашу проблему я не знаю.

Comment: @Viktorov Спасибо, надеюсь там решится моя задача. Как раз подхожу к этому разделу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот примерный триггер для решения вашей задачи для MS SQL:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TRG_InsertUpdSales') IS NOT NULL
DROP TRIGGER TRG_InsertUpdSales
GO

CREATE TRIGGER TRG_InsertUpdSales
ON dbo.Table2
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
UPDATE Table1 set sales=sum(column1) from Table2 where Table1.user=Table2.user
SELECT * FROM INSERTED
END
GO
```

Comment: почему из всех приведенных тэгов вопроса, вы выбрали `sqlserver` которого там нет?:)

Comment: @teran я предположил что синтаксис создания триггеров в больнстве случаев примерно одинаков, но подстраховался тем что указал "платфому" решения)

Comment: Также необходимы триггеры на обновление и удаление - возврат товара никто не отменял. Равно как и ошибки ввода.

Comment: @NickProskuryakov Извините за столь поздний ответ, но можно это как то сделать на sqlite

Answer (score 0):

По идее так:

```
SELECT user.name,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE orders.user_id = user.id) as ordersCount
FROM user
```

Answer (score 0):

Создай представление, это лучше чем использовать триггер каждый раз после инсерта во вторую таблицу

Comment: На большом объеме такой подход равносилен выстрелу в ногу. Триггер пересчитает только 1 раз, а для представления придется пересчитывать снова и снова

Comment: Хорошо, учту. Отвечал из тех соображений, что если активно идут инсерты во вторую таблицу, то это приводит к вызову триггера + апдейта в первую таблицу. А использую вьюху, мы будем подсчитывать только когда необходимо получить результат. Как правило всегда видел такой подход. Возможно проще завести переменную, которая будет инкрементить кол-во строк и выводить в селекте эту переменную.